# If $\frac{df}{dx}$ is monotone $\implies$ $f$ is monotone?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, derivatives, monotone-functions

If $f$ is monotone then derivative of $f$ is monotone.

Counter-example is $x^3$.

But if $\frac{df}{dx}$ is monotone $\implies$ $f$  is monotone?This is the question I can't solve.

Comment: $f(x) = x^2$ :)

Comment: Assuming everthing is differentiable, a function is monotone is the same as its first derivative NOT CHANGING sign (the first derivate can be as wild as you like, but if it remains positive/negative, the function will remain increasing/decreasing).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not true, take $f(x) = x^2$. Its derivative is $f'(x) = 2x$, which is strictly increasing, but $f$ is not monotone. You really want $f' \geq 0$ or $f' \leq 0$ to ensure that $f$ is monotone.

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, an image could help explain this. In the plot below, $f(x) = x^2$ is plotted in blue and $f'(x) = 2x$ is plotted in red. As you can see, $f$ changes direction at $x = 0$, even though $f'$ is always monotonically increasing. It's not a coincidence that $x = 0$ is also the root of $f'$! When $x \leq 0$, $f'(x) \leq 0$ so $f$ is decreasing, and when $x \geq 0$, $f'(x) \geq 0$ so $f$ is increasing.

[image: 1]

There is something notable about the assumption that $f'$ is monontically increasing though. Notice that in the above plot, $f$ is shaped upwards. This is a consequence of $f'$ being monotonically increasing, as it means that the curve becomes steeper and steeper the further out you go. The opposite can happen, where $f'(x)$ is monotonically decreasing and you will see that the plot of $f$ is then shaped downwards. For instance, $f(x) = \log(x)$ has $f'(x) = 1/x$. See below, where again $f$ is blue and $f'$ is red.

[image]

EDIT 2: As pointed out by @MartinR in the comments, I should tell you the official terminology for saying that the plot is "upwards" or "downwards" facing. The "upwards" plots like $f(x)=x^2$ are called convex, and the "downward" plots like $f(x) = \log(x)$ are called concave.

Comment: Isn't it $f'(x)=2x$?

Comment: Please check other answers or comments before answering a question. Your question does not give more input or information than the comment did. Please either elaborate on your answer or encourage the user who wrote the comment to post an answer. Thank you.

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter Of course! Thanks for that, it was a silly mistake. I'll edit it now.

Comment: @vitamind I see your point but I wrote my answer simultaneously to the comment so I did not see it before submitting, and I gave information about an actual condition on the derivative that does ensure monotonicity.

Comment: @paulblartmathcop The user who wrote the comment 3 minutes after the post. But I understand, it happens. I just wanted to make that clear since some users intentionally copy ideas in their comments to implement them into their answers without writing further ideas or concepts . Maybe adding an image would help the OP. Thanks for responding, have a nice day!

Comment: @vitamind Thanks for the suggestion, I added some plots and I think they aid the explanation. You have a nice day as well!

Comment: @paulblartmathcop (+1) Very nice answer!

Comment: “$f$ is shaped upward/downward” – you could mention that this is called “convex” (resp. “concave”).

Comment: @vitamind Thank you!

Comment: And @MartinR that's a good point, I'll include that now.